# Creating a facebook application with restfb?

Tags: facebook

I want to create a very basic application with restfb which just prints the name of the user. Can anyone please tell me how do I start. I am not clear about the flow of the application ???

One more thing can I test it first with tomcat i'e without uploading the WAR file on live server ???

Your help will get me going.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean with rest API? Use graph api instead. The Rest api is being deprecated! Your app may not work From near future onwards.:)
Did this help? If it did consider accepting the answer!

Comment: No I am talking about the RestFB api which is a facebook graph api written in java. Do you have any idea about it ??